# check null value express validator

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express validator to validate post data on server. Thing is working fine but when I am trying to check null value it is not working..

I have tried

```
req.checkBody('title', 'Title is required').isLength({ min: 1, max:50 });

req.checkBody('title', 'Title is required').trim().notEmpty();
```

for both null value is saving to DB.

How can I check null value in express validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
req.checkBody('title', 'Title is required').exists({checkFalsy: true}).isLength({ min: 1, max:50 });
```

Answer (score 0):

from documentation:

checkNull: if true, fields with null values will not exist

checkFalsy: if true, fields with falsy values (eg "", 0, false, null) will also not exist

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html